# Ensure password does not contain dictionary words

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I am planning to implement a solution in java, which checks whether the user password does not contain dictionary words whether it is English, Spanish, German or French.

I am having the list of words from here :
ftp://ftp.openwall.com/pub/wordlists/languages/English/

I am thinking to use a HashMap or use a cache like redis which will contain all words from dictionary as words. Although that might not be efficient.

What would be the best way of impementation ?

Comment: Please don't implement that at all, what is the point of this system? Is your goal forcing users to write down their passwords on post-its and sticking them to their monitor? Because that is what you are going to get.

Comment: [a little explaination](https://xkcd.com/936/) (as a comic, but it's serious)

Comment: @luk2302 : I agree,but what would be the alternative that is part of password policy...

Comment: Not having a password policy. The more elaborate your policy is the more likely it is the passwords will be written down. If you really want one you can go for "10+ characters and contain numbers + letters", everything more restrictive is annoying as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really your requirement, I suggest to use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure which is great for finding quickly words in a dictionary.

You can get an implementation of a trie in `org.apache.commons.collections4`. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Trie.html

With a trie you would need to build it from the dictionary and hold it in memory. Then you would need to traverse the string from right to left and see if you can lookup results in the trie. If no results are found then there are no parts of the password which are in the dictionary.

Tries are very efficient at finding string pattern, because they use a tree like structure.

If you want to use the Apache Commons trie on a Maven project use this import dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a simple toy example which finds dictionary words in the string "hellothere":

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.Trie;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.trie.PatriciaTrie;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.trie.UnmodifiableTrie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TrieDict {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trie<String, String> trie = new UnmodifiableTrie<>(new PatriciaTrie<>(fillMap()));
        String pwd = "hellothere";
        System.out.println(extractDictMatches(trie, pwd));
    }

    // Provides a dictionary
    private static Map<String, String> fillMap() {
        return ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().
                put("there", "there").
                put("is", "is").
                put("word", "word").
                put("here", "here").
                put("hell", "hell").
                build();
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> extractDictMatches(Trie<String, String> trie, String pwd) {
        return IntStream.range(0, pwd.length()).collect(ArrayList::new, (objects, i) -> {
            String suffix = pwd.substring(i);
            IntStream.rangeClosed(0, suffix.length()).forEach(j -> {
                String suffixCut = suffix.substring(0, j);
                if (suffixCut.length() > 2) {
                    if (trie.containsKey(suffixCut)) {
                        objects.add(suffixCut);
                    }
                }
            });
        }, (objects, i) -> {
        });
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
[hell, there, here]
```